# Is there a way to give all Objects a method without modifying Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to augment all Objects in my Node.js application with a logging function, such that each object can call `this.log` or have its `log` function referenced by `thatObject.log`. I see a number of advantages in doing this:

- I can modify each object's `log` function so it produces special output, and
- If no object specific `log` function is provided, it can find a `log` function up its prototype chain, and
- In the global context, `this.log` refers to `Object.prototype.log`, and in any other context, `this.log` refers to that object's `log`.

For example:

```
Object.prototype.log = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
};

function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.log = function(message) {
    console.log(this.name + " says " + message);
};

function Ghost() {
};

var joe = new Person("joe");
joe.log("Hi!"); //"Joe says Hi!"
var boo = new Ghost();
boo.log("Boo!"); //"Boo!"

//I can call this in any object context, and get a context-specific message
//This includes the global context, like so
this.log("Log!"); //"Log!"
```

Unfortunately, due to limitations in external dependencies, I can't modify Object.prototype (not simply a namespacing issue). **Is there a way of doing this without modifying Object.prototype?**

Most importantly, I would like to preserve the behaviour of calling `this.log` from anywhere.

**UPDATE:** I've found a workaround for this specific problem. [See my answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997997/3092090)

Comment: Although the answer right now is 'no', Reginald Braithwaite had an awesome blog about this just a couple of days ago http://raganwald.com/2015/08/08/monkey-patching-extension-methods-bind-operator.html. See also this proposal for ES 2016 http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add some property to an object, you can add it as an own property (if you have a reference to the object), or somewhere in its prototypical chain.

In this case, you want to add it to all objects. I think it's reasonable to assume that you don't have references to all of them. So the only way is adding the property in the prototypical chain.

For example, you could add the property to `Array.prototype`, `Function.prototype`, ...

However, that won't affect objects that don't inherit from those. Specially, an usual way to create objects is using object initializers: `{}`. Those objects only inherit from `Object.prototype`.

Therefore, for those, `Object.prototype` is your **only option**.

However, that **isn't enough**. It's possible to create objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype`. For example `Object.create(null)`.

So no, it's **not possible**. And IMO that's a **good thing**, because you shouldn't pollute objects you don't own.

Answer (score 1):

As Oriol already pointed out, no its not possible. Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
var log = function(message) {
  var msg = message || '';
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this) + msg);
}

//later in the code
log.call(this, 'Log!'); //prints the stringified Object plus 'Log!'
```

another alternative if you use constructor functions would be to have all of them inherit from a constructor function with the desired method (although admittedly that doesn't satisfy your 'even global context' requirement).

Comment: `.call` was something I hadn't considered, good call (heh). `JSON.stringify` is overkill though.

Comment: Just a proxy for any `this`-related behavior you need. But yeah, call/apply/bind rule.

Answer (score 0):

While I've accepted Oriol's answer as the best answer for the original question, I have found a usable workaround for my specific problem, enabling `log` from any context:

- Define a `log` function in the global scope, enabling `this.log` for when `this` refers to the global object, and
- Create a `Logger` class with a `log` function defined on its prototype.
- Make any classes with `log` functionality have `Logger` in the prototype chain somewhere.

This isn't ideal, because now classes have to have `Logger` in their prototype chain somewhere, either added manually or inherited, but it does ensure the `log` function will exist for that class. Implemented in the original example,

```
function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

function Logger() {};

Logger.prototype.log = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
};

function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype = Object.create(Logger.prototype);

Person.prototype.log = function(message) {
    console.log(this.name + " says " + message);
};

function Ghost() {
};

Ghost.prototype = Object.create(Logger.prototype);

var joe = new Person("joe");
joe.log("Hi!"); //"Joe says Hi!"
var boo = new Ghost();
boo.log("Boo!"); //"Boo!"
this.log("Log!"); //"Log!"
```